# error: function does not have any attributes rk4

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have been trying to run the following code for long and every troubleshooting attempt has led me to another. The code is for solving the TOV equations and present a M-R graph for a neutron star. Please if anyone could help with it, it would be greatly appreciated.

The code has been taken from the following link: https://www.ictp-saifr.org/schoolgr/Lecture2Creighton.pdf

Just to clarify, I have been using Python 3.8, and the code is 9 years old so that might as well be the problem but i tried running it on a 2.x compiler and faced the same issue. Thanks in advance.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.constants import pi, G, c, hbar, m_n

Msun = 1.98892e30

Gamma0 = 5.0/3.0
K0 = (3.0*pi**2)**(2.0/3.0)*hbar**2/(5.0*m_n**(8.0/3.0))
Gamma1 = 3.0
rho1 = 5e17
P1 = K0*rho1**Gamma0
K1 = P1/rho1**Gamma1

def eos(rho):
    if rho < rho1: return K0*rho**Gamma0
    else: return K1*rho**Gamma1

def inveos(P):
    if P < P1: return (P/K0)**(1.0/Gamma0)
    else: return (P/K1)**(1.0/Gamma1) 

def tov(y,r):
    P, m = y[0], y[1]
    rho = inveos(P)
    dPdr = -G*(rho + P/c**2)*(m + 4.0*pi*r**3*P/c**2)
    dPdr = dPdr/(r*(r - 2.0*G*m/c**2))
    dmdr = 4.0*pi*r**2*rho
    return np.array([dPdr, dmdr])

def tovsolve(rhoc):
    r = np.arange(10.0, 20000.0, 1)
    m =  np.zeros_like(r)
    P =  np.zeros_like(r)
    m[0] = 4.0*pi*r[0]**3*rhoc
    P[0] = eos(rhoc)
    y = np.array((P[0],m[0]))
    i = 0
    while P[i] > 0.0 and i <len(r)-1:
        dr = r[i+1] - r[i]
        y = odeint.rk4(tov, y, r[i], dr)
        P[i+1] = y[0]
        m[i+1] = y[1]
        i = i+1
    return m[i-1]/Msun, r[i-1]/1000

rhoc = np.logspace(17.5,20)
M = np.zeros_like(rhoc)
R = np.zeros_like(rhoc)
for i in range(len(rhoc)):
    M[i], R[i] = tovsolve(rhoc[i])

plt.plot(R,M)
plt.xlabel('Radius (km)')
plt.ylabel('Mass (Solar Masses)')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `y = np.array(P[0],m[0])`. It seems you forgot the brackets here, try `y = np.array([P[0],m[0]])`

Comment: Also a parenthesis is missing on the call to odeint...

Comment: Aah! Right right. Thanks. There is another issue popping up now tho, it says the "function does not have any attributes rk4"

Comment: In the paper the import is `import pylab, odeint`.  It doesn't look like this `odeint` is from `scipy.integrate`.  You might get by with `odeint(tov, y, r[i], dr)`, but you need to check that your arguments match its docs.  Or better yet use `solve_ivp`

Comment: When you get an AttributeError, the first place you should check is the docs.  Asking us can come later.

Comment: Thanks thanks! I see. I couldn't find odeint as a separate module so I thought maybe doing it this way would work the same. Can you explain how to solve the same using solve_ivp? I don't have much of an idea and this is kinda urgent.